# How to evaluate/expand a generator expression that is inside a generator expression?

Tags: cmake

I am currently working on a project where I need to make use of generator expressions to obtain some properties of CMake targets. Therefore, consider the following `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(fruit_proj)

add_custom_target(banana)
set_target_properties(banana PROPERTIES COLOR "yellow")

add_custom_target(fruit)
set_target_properties(fruit PROPERTIES COLOR $<TARGET_PROPERTY:banana,COLOR>)

file(GENERATE OUTPUT color.txt CONTENT $<TARGET_PROPERTY:fruit,COLOR>)
```

Note the chained usage of the `$<TARGET_PROPERTY>` generator expression that gets the value of the `COLOR` property of `fruit`, which itself is a generator expression to get the `COLOR` property of `banana`.

I kind of hoped that the content of the generated `color.txt` file would be

```
yellow
```

while in fact it turns out to be

```
$<TARGET_PROPERTY:banana,COLOR>
```

i.e. only the first generator expression was evaluated.

Is there any way to recursively evaluate the generator expressions to get the desired output or is that not possible in CMake?

Looking forward to your suggestions :)

PS: I cannot use `get_target_property` since the order of the target generation is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of a generator expression is itself a generator expression, then for get inner expression to be evaluated wrap it with [$<GENEX_EVAL>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:GENEX_EVAL):

```cmake
file(GENERATE OUTPUT color.txt CONTENT $<GENEX_EVAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:fruit,COLOR>>)
```